# TianoCore UEFI Development Kit build configuration on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, uefi

How to properly install EDK2 on Windows? I'm trying to follow [this](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/UDK2017-How-to-Build#how-to-build-windows-system) instructions, but it doesn't work...

- created C:\EFIWorkSpace
- Created Win32 in C:\EFIWorkspace\BaseTools\Bin from [BaseTools](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-BaseTools-win32)
- set PYTHON_HOME=C:\Python27
- set CYGWIN_HOME=C:\cygwin64

The errors begin when I'm trying to execute `build` in `C:\EFIWorkSpace>`

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASO1Y.jpg

(`c:\efiworkspace\MdePkg\Library\BasePeCoffLib\BasePeCoffLib.inf [IA32]` - System cannot find certain path]

How can i set these kits to use it further in Visual Studio 2017? I want to build  an UEFI Application. Maybe someone knows a good youtube tutorial?  I will appreciate any help.

Comment: At a glance I see `no space left on device` error. Start with resolving this issue first and see if your problem persists

Comment: @AlexanderZhak Yes, my bad! I fixed that. Now the problem is with executing build

Comment: Updated a screenshot

Comment: Looks like you problem is in `Toolchain=MYTOOLS` setting. Most probably you didn't set paths to VS binaries correctly. Check out config files in `BaseTools/Conf` directory (`tools_def.txt`, `target.txt`, etc. -- if I remember the names correctly). They contain many examples of toolchains configurations and how to apply them to you workspace so you'll be able to configure it properly for VS2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the ToolChain in target.txt from MYTOOLS to match your toolchain (VS2017x86). Also, note that UDK2017 doesn't officially support the VS2017 toolchain. Please use UDK2018.

https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/UDK2018-Key-Features

https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/UDK2018-How-to-Build

Comment: I followed the instructions, but i still have some errors, https://imgur.com/a/1HQivqi
@TianoCore Admin

Comment: Mistake in my previous reply - Try 'VS2017' for the toolchain value instead of 'VS2017x86'.